# AJAX - how to load javascript code not html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-load

I use jQuery with `$('#countryid').load('/some/url',{country: country_id});` function to automatically load options for regions depending on selected country before.

And it works fine when I load html through ajax.

But I need to load javascript code. When I try to do that all select fields disappear from page at all...

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countrydropdown').change(function() {
        var countryvalue = $('#countrydropdown option:selected').val();
        if(countryvalue==0){clearlist();}
        getarea();
    });
});
function getarea(){
    var countryvalue = $('#countrydropdown option:selected').val();
    var area = $('#areadropdown');
    if(countryvalue==0){
        area.attr("disabled",true);
    }else{
        area.attr("disabled",false);
        area.load('/ajax/2/',{country: countryvalue});
    }
}
function clearlist(){
    $('#areadropdown').empty();
}
</script>

<form action="" id="form">
    <select id="countrydropdown">
        <option value="0">Countries</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select id="areadropdown" disabled="disabled">

    </select>
</form>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please post your javascript code which you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code your comment on my previous answer suggests you are using:

> `<script type="text/javascript">for(var i in arr) document.write(arr[i]);</script>`

After the page has loaded, the document will enter the closed state.

You cannot `document.write` to a document in the cosed state, so `document.open` will be automatically called.

This will trash the existing document so a new one can be written.

Use [DOM](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML) to manipulate the document, don't go near `document.write`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval to execute javascript code

```
eval(ajax.request);
```

Comment: If `eval()` is the only solution to your problem, you really need to think of an alternative method and restructure your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading **just** JavaScript, then use [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of `load`.

If you are loading a combination of HTML then JavaScript, then I would give serious consideration to refactoring so that the JavaScript is already in place and events are handled using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of being bound directly to the elements themselves.

Comment: What's the difference between html and `<script type="text/javascript">for(var i in arr) document.write(arr[i]);</script>`? I can say - it is also html.

Comment: Scripts get special handling when they hit `innerHTML` … but now you've shown us the code you are trying to run… see the other answer I'm about to write.